# c# Click on form and do click when window is infocused

Tags: c#, winforms, click, focus

I have windowsform application. And the problem is when i have focused another window and i just want click to my application,  firstly click is to focus the window and then need to just do 2nd click on button for example. How can i do that when : i click on my winform applicatoin when window is infocused and this click  just click this place not only focus winform application.

Please be patient for newbie . I just learn. When you don't uderstand my question feel free to just ask.

Comment: It depends on what you click on.  A second click is required in the specific case of having a ToolStrip in your form.  Don't force us to guess at this, it is not useful.

Comment: When i'm just on another window and i click on button in my windowform it sometimes click this button and sometimes i just need to click 2nd time. Is any possible to always click this button when my winform is't focused?